# Image to be seen big onTapping in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am getting posts from a wordpress website into a flutter app.

Each post has 3 pictures and this is the layout of the images
[image]

What I am trying to do is when I Tap on IMAGE 1 or IMAGE 2 or IMAGE 3, that image will be shown on MAIN IMAGE.

Does it makes sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You need to use a [stateful](https://flutter.io/tutorials/interactive/#stateful-stateless) widget
- You may use [`Column`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Column-class.html) and [`Row`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Row-class.html) to achieve that layout.
- And [`Image`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Image-class.html) to display the images within the layout.
- You may specifically use [`Image.network(url)`](https://flutter.io/cookbook/images/network-image/) constructor to show images from your word press site.
- The image1, image2 and image3 can be wrapped in a [`InkWell`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/InkWell-class.html) widget. And `InkWell`'s `onTap` can have code to update the url/image of the Main Image widget within a [`setState()`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html)

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 4):

i Hope That Below Code help you. in following code i used network image but you can also used assert images to.

```
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

  void main() => runApp(new Demo());

  class Demo extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    _DemoState createState() => _DemoState();
  }

  class _DemoState extends State<Demo> with TickerProviderStateMixin {


    String image1 = "http://via.placeholder.com/350x150";
    String image2 = "http://via.placeholder.com/200x150";
    String image3 = "http://via.placeholder.com/200x150";
    String currentMainImage = "http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" ;
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: new Text("table demo"),
          ),
          body: new Container(
            child: new Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                    height:150.0,
                    child: new Image.network(currentMainImage,fit: BoxFit.fill,)
                ),
                new Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(
                      child: InkWell(
                        onTap : (){
                            setState(() {
                              currentMainImage = image1;
                            });
                        },
                        child: new Image.network(image1)
                       )
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                        child: InkWell(
                            onTap : (){
                              setState(() {
                                currentMainImage = image2;
                              });
                            },
                            child: new Image.network(image2)
                        )
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                        child: InkWell(
                            onTap : (){
                              setState(() {
                                currentMainImage = image3;
                              });
                            },
                            child: new Image.network(image3)
                        )
                    ),
                  ],
                )
              ],

            )
          )
        )
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: Nice. Just have a problem. I am doing this in a separate dart file that is called when I press a button. That button also sends a Object with all the info needed to display on this gattery (title, description and images).

So this Object is being used as widget.single_gallery.